# Date range also filters the same day from another month?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, filter, date-range

I am using [dt-date_range_filter](https://github.com/hemantrai88/datatables-date_range_filter), my date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Setting the minimum date to `2015-09-11` and the maximum date to `2015-09-24` also returns a result with the date `2015-10-15`, as seen here:

[image: screenshot]

This is my code on call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        $( "#min" ).datepicker();
    });

    $(function() {
        $( "#max" ).datepicker();
    });

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

    lengthChange: true,
         buttons: [
            'print'
        ],
        "oSelectorOpts": {
            page: 'current'
        },

        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                            i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 5 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                } );

            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 5, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(
                '<center>Total Sales <br>'+'P '+ pageTotal+'.00'
            );
        }
    } );
    $('#min').change( function() { table.fnDraw(); } );
    $('#max').change( function() { table.fnDraw(); } );
    table.buttons().container()
        .appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );
} );

</script>
```

It's like it's not filtering at all because the same day from another month is also filtered?

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if (dd<10)
        dd = '0'+dd;

        if (mm<10)
        mm = '0'+mm;

        today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

        if ($('#min').val() != '' || $('#max').val() != '') {
        var iMin_temp = $('#min').val();
        if (iMin_temp == '') {
            iMin_temp = '1980-01-01';
        }

        var iMax_temp = $('#max').val();
        if (iMax_temp == '') {
            iMax_temp = today;
        }

        var arr_min = iMin_temp.split("-");
        var arr_max = iMax_temp.split("-");
        var arr_date = aData[7].split("-");

        var iMin = new Date(arr_min[2], arr_min[0], arr_min[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)
        var iMax = new Date(arr_max[2], arr_max[0], arr_max[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)
        var iDate = new Date(arr_date[2], arr_date[0], arr_date[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)

        if ( iMin == "" && iMax == "" )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( iMin == "" && iDate < iMax )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( iMin <= iDate && "" == iMax )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( iMin <= iDate && iDate <= iMax )
        {
            return true;
        }
            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the way you use the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor in Javascript.

> Creates a JavaScript `Date` instance that represents a single moment in time. `Date` objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC.
>
> **Constructor**
>
> ```
> new Date();
> new Date(value);
> new Date(dateString);
> new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
> ```

The order of the last constructor, which you use, is `year, month, day`.

However, your code does this, paraphrased:

```
'2015-10-15'.split("-");
```

Which returns this array:

```
[0]: "2015"
[1]: "10"
[2]: "15"
```

You then write this:

```
new Date(arr_date[2], arr_date[0], arr_date[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Which means this:

```
new Date("15", "2015", "10", 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

You are inputting the order `day, year, month`, resulting in the wrong date.

Your current input results in this:

```
min:  Array [ "2015", "09", "11" ]
max:  Array [ "2015", "09", "24" ]
date: Array [ "2015", "10", "15" ]

min:  Date 2078-12-08T23:00:00.000Z
max:  Date 2091-12-08T23:00:00.000Z
date: Date 2082-12-09T23:00:00.000Z
```

You generate wrong dates, making the filter fail because `2082-12-09T23:00:00.000Z` is indeed between `2078-12-08T23:00:00.000Z` and `2091-12-08T23:00:00.000Z`.

Therefore the correct code is as follows:

```
var iMin  = new Date( arr_min[0],  arr_min[1],  arr_min[2], 0, 0, 0, 0);
var iMax  = new Date( arr_max[0],  arr_max[1],  arr_max[2], 0, 0, 0, 0);
var iDate = new Date(arr_date[0], arr_date[1], arr_date[2], 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: can you please point out to me what code to change? I dont know why this does not work.

Comment: @glendonphilippbaculio Updated answer.

Comment: @glendonphilippbaculio add`console.log(iMin, iMax, iDate);` after the modified code and copy the output from the console (ctrl + shift + J) so I can see the values.

Comment: it's <input class="form-control" name="date" type="text" id="min" value="2015-09-11" readonly=""> on the min

Comment: @glendonphilippbaculio That can't be right, it should output 3 `Date` objects, not elements.

Comment: THANKS, just deleted the cookies and restart browser, solved!.